# Don't create a lambda when tear-off will do

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `get` function in my dart file where i have used a lambda. I am using DartLint which tells me not to create lambda if tear-off will do. I am not sure how to use a tear-off in my use case.

`///To change data to our Stream using Sink.
  Function(dynamic) get changeData => (event) {
        _dataBlocController.add(event);
      };`

This is my lambda function, how will a tear-off look for this. I have gone through the documentation, but i am not getting a syntactically correct solution.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This means that the closure is useless.

Instead of:

```
get changeData => (event) => _foo.add(event);
```

you can do:

```
get changeData => _foo.add;
```

Comment: Hi, will we have performance improvement with this?

Comment: I would say no. You will have simpler code, but internally it's exactly the same.

Comment: There is a performance impact, yes. Creating a closure has a small cost and impacts how some variables are garbage collected.